# Need other ways to write a SELECT query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find a way which will help to fetch records based on a condition.

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    Email NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO Student VALUES('James', 'james@test.com'),('Alex', 'alex@example.com'),('Jack', 'jack@test.com'),('Robby', 'robby@example.com')
```

Problem: I need to fetch all the students whose email address ends with '%test.com' based on a variable.

```
DECLARE @fetchTestDotComStudents BIT = 1

-- Now if @fetchTestDotComStudents is 1 then fetch only @test.com students else fetch all students.
-- Below is the query I used

IF(@fetchTestDotComStudents = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Student
    WHERE Email LIKE '%@test.com'
END
ELSE IF(@fetchTestDotComStudents = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Student
END
```

Is there any other way where I can use a CASE statement instead of IF-ELSE clause. This will also reduce redundancy.

Expect different ways to find the result.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your asking, but the above seems like the right method for what you have. A `CASE` would lower performance, and proper boolean logic would result in poor query plan cached for the *other* scenario. Based on  the simplicity, `IF...ELSE` seems the correct thing to do.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu

Comment: @Larnu - Do you have any reference to back up what you are saying? Any recent version of SQL Server will certainly be able to optimse a plan with an OR on a single variable....

Comment: Thank you all for the solution.

Comment: @Milney How about [#BackToBasics: An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and [Catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student
WHERE (Email LIKE '%@test.com' AND @fetchTestDotComStudents = 1)
      OR
      @fetchTestDotComStudents = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an OR:

```
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE Email LIKE '%@test.com' OR @fetchTestDotComStudents = 0
```

Comment: As i mention in the comments on the answer, this could well end up with a badly cached query plan. If `@fetchTestDotComStudents` has a value other than 1, SQL Server will cache the plan for what is likely a small data set. When a query for `@fetchTestDotComStudents = 0` is then run, the cached plan will be used, and likely the estimates will be very wrong. The simplicity here may mean that it "isn't" an issue, but with other queries this can cause some real performance problems; and why I recommended that actually the OP is likely better of with `IF...ELSE`.

Answer (score 0):

If this table is large, and you are frequently searching in this way, you might want to consider adding an extra column.  The LIKE clause with leading % requires a clustered index scan of the entire table.  You could put a nonclustered index on Istest which will drastically speed up your query.  If your table is small, then this is probably overkill.

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    Email NVARCHAR(255),
    IsTest bit
)

SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE IsTest = 1 OR Istest = @fetchTestDotComStudents   --Grabs everything if variable is 0.
```